# Configuring Terraform provider AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, terraform, identity-management

[image: sc1]

[image]

This is what I am getting when trying to Terraform plan for the first time.

[image: line 11 SC]

> Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 96f0839a-abf6-415c-b886-66d41933cbc8, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.

- Created new IAM user on AWS
- Used same credentials on the VScode extension on it worked for the extension.

I expect this to work smoothly, as I ran out of errors to check for.

Comment: The error tells you to look at line 11 in main.tf file.What do you have there? Paste the errors/code snippets in your question instead of images.

Comment: yes and line 11 looks great  would upload a SC right away

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the attribute with a string intead to read the variable value.

Instead of

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-1"
  access_key = "var.access_key"
  secret_key = "var.secret_key"
}
```

you should remove the quotes so it can read the variables values.

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-1"
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
}
```